# mysql group by and average for non zero values

Tags: mysql

I have a table as below

```
carrier   duration   date
a         10         05-09-2013 
a         0          04-09-2013 
b         1          05-09-2013 
b         3          04-09-2013  
c         2          05-09-2013 
c         3          04-09-2013
```

i would like to calculate the avg based on the carrier and on the total duration

the result should  be:

```
carrier a = avg is 10
carrier b = avg is 2
carrier c = ave is 2.5
```

it should calculate the total duration for the non zero values only so for carrier A since it dint had any activity in 04-09-2013 date then the avg should be 10/1 i.e total duration/ number of dates with non- zero duration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select                  
  carrier,           -- carrier column in result set
  avg(duration)      -- average duration column in result set
from tablename       -- specify what table to get results from
where duration>0     -- condition excluding table rows where duration=0
group by carrier;    -- All rows with the same 'carrier' value are grouped 
                     -- together into one row in the result set. This works with 
                     -- the aggregate function avg();
```

Comment: i would like to use sum ( duration) / count of dates with non zero duration values for calculating the duration.

Comment: The statement I gave you is equivalent

Answer (score 0):

```
select carrier, avg(duration) 
from mytable
where duration > 0
group by carrier
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select carrier,AVG(duration) as average_duration
from tablename
where duration != 0
group by carrier
```